# Cannot retrieve active ActionCable channels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, actioncable

I am building a notification relay into our Rails app and having difficulty returning the active channels. I have read other questions that state using `Redis.new.pubsub("channels", "action_cable/*")` will return the pub/sub channels but I always receive an empty array. I have been using `redis-cli monitor` to see that there is communication and everything in the rails app is working fine, I just cannot return the active pub/sub channels.

I am working in development mode and have updated my **cable.yml** file as below:

```
default: &default
adapter: redis
url: redis://localhost:6379/1

development:
  <<: *default

test:
  <<: *default

production:
  <<: *default
```

Redis is showing the connection is made and the channels are created:

[image: Redis Monitor Output]

When I try to query the pub/subs I get the empty array:

[image]

Rails 5.2.2.1, Ruby 2.6.2, Redis 4.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to retrieve my channels by using `Redis.new.pubsub("channels", "notification_*")` instead of `Redis.new.pubsub("channels", "action_cable/*")`.

[image: rails console returning correct channels]